# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined and a walk around

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

there is an object contactBook defined as below. I send it to redux and get it back in the exactly same format.

```
{“Book1” : [{name: “Bob”},{name, “Jane”}, {name, “Mary”]}
```

I intended to transfer it to a name list

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import * as actions from "../redux/actions";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class ListContactComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.startLoadingContacts(this.props.match.params.bookName);
    }


    addContactClicked = () => {
        this.props.history.push({
            pathname: `/addressBook/contact/`,
            state: this.state.bookName
        })
    };

    render() {
        let contacts = Object.values(this.props.contacts).flat();
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h3>All Contacts</h3>
                {this.state.message && <div class="alert alert-success">{this.state.message}</div>}
                <div className="container">
                    <table className="table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Phone Number</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {
                            contacts.map(
                                (contact, index) =>
                                        <tr key={index}>
                                            <td>{contact.name}</td>
                                            <td>{contact.phoneNumber}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                )
                        }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <div className="row">
                        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.addContactClicked}>Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        contacts: state.contacts
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
}

const connectedContactList = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ListContactComponent));
export {connectedContactList as ListContactComponent};
```

1. if I use:

   contacts = contactsBook[Book1]

I got TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

what’s the cause of this error, and how to fix it?

if I don't use the objected returned from redux, it just works fine. I don't really know what's difference?

Actions:

```
export function startLoadingContacts(addressBookName) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return AddressBookDataService
            .retrieveContacts(addressBookName)
            .then(
                (response) => {
                    let contacts = {};
                    contacts[addressBookName] = response.data;
                    dispatch(loadContacts(contacts))
                }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
}

export function loadContacts(contacts) {
    return {
        type: 'LOAD_CONTACTS',
        contacts
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
function contacts(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_CONTACT':
            return "....";
        case 'LOAD_CONTACTS':
            return action.contacts;
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

- console log:

  ```
             contactsBook:

               {Book1: Array(3)}

                      Book1: Array(3)

                          0: {name: "Bob"}  

                          1: {name: "Jane"}  

                          2: {name: "Mary"}    

                           length: 3      

                      __proto__: Array(0)  

                      __proto__: Object



             contacts:

                   (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

                       0: {name: "Bob"}        

                       1: {name: "Jane"}        

                       2: {name: "Mary"}       

                       length: 3
  ```

  or

  2. if I use:      `contacts = Object.values(contactsBook)`,
     there is no output.

  console log:

  ```
   [Array(3)]

       0: Array(3)

           0: {name: "Bob"}        

            1: {name: "Jane"}        

            2: {name: "Mary"}         

            length: 3     

             __proto__: Array(0)       

             length: 1
  ```

when using JSON.stringy(contacts),

it prints:

`[[ {name: "Bob"} ,..]] rather than [{name: "Bob"},..  ]`

In this case, How to get rid of the outer []?

if mocking up a data warper =[[data]], I can remove the outer layer by warper[0].

but it doesn't work for

`contacts = Object.values(contactsBook)
 contacts[0]`

finally flat() solved this problem

`contacts = Object.values(contactsBook).flat()`

Could you please help explain the reason?

Comment: `contactsBook[Book1]` ? Do you mean either `contactsBook["Book1"]` or `contactsBook.Book1`?

Comment: Are you trying to map `contacts` or `contactsBook`? Or both?

Comment: None of them work for me. I even tried `contactsBook['${bookName}']`

Comment: Please add entire component code for the component you're trying to render these in. Specifically, the export (or hook) that is connecting it to your redux store, and any function calls/updates/etc to `contacts`/`contactsBook` and where they are rendered.

Comment: map on contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, you need to add initial state to your reducer that isn't an empty object, like an empty array `[]`. This way when the component first renders and is connected to redux, it'll have a defined value that is valid to map over.

**edit**

Ok, so your state shape *was* `{[book: string]: string[]}`. In this case the initial state (`{}`) for the reducer *was* fine and you *do* need to grab the book name from the route params. Here I've updated the `mapStateToProps` function to also pull in the component's own props and do the computation to return the `contactList` as a prop to the component.

**/edit**

Reducer

```
const initialState = {};

function contacts(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_CONTACT':
            return "....";
        case 'LOAD_CONTACTS':
            return action.contacts;
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Component

```
const { contactList } = this.props;

...

contactList.map(...

...

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const { match: { params: { bookName } } = ownProps;
  return {
    contactList: state.contacts[bookName] || [],
  }
}
```

**Alternative Solution** Guard Pattern

```
{
  contacts && contacts.map(
    (contact, index) => (
       <tr key={index}>
         <td>{contact.name}</td>
         <td>{contact.phoneNumber}</td>
       </tr>
  ))
}
```

Comment: This first suggest solution should work as well , if I change it a bit   

`const {match, contacts} = this.props;
        const bookName = match.params.bookName;
        const contactList = contacts[bookName] || [];

….
contactList.map’

Comment: @AndrewXie Ah, this also explains my misunderstanding about your state shape. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your map function to this:

```
{contacts["Book1"].map((contact, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{contact.name}</td>
            <td>{contact.phoneNumber}</td>
          </tr>
))}
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-pevdn

Comment: Yes, it works as I said, but it doesn't work when it returned from redux